# How to stop to clean mongo db once Meteor is reset [Meteor]

Tags: mongodb, meteor

i am new user of Meteor + Mongo DB . I have seen once Meteor server is stopped or reset  all Mongo db data is lost , how will stop to clean the mongo db.

Suppose i have Registration related data entry in Mongo DB , next time when i will make the new user registration , it should add one more Document in Collection.

Now it always clean mong DB once Meteor is reset or stopped.

regards,
Rakesh kumar Jha

Comment: Did my answer helped you or do you still have a problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

A look at the documentation of [`meteor reset`](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorreset) states the following:

> Reset the current project to a fresh state. Removes the local mongo database.

Now there is to consider, that you won't do this in production because in production you will have no  Meteor installed but a "normal" Node application running.

In development you can also "reset" your app without removing the local mongo db:

1. Make sure your app is **not** running
2. Open a terminal and cd to your project root, then enter the following commands:
3. `rm -rf node_modules`  to remove your node packages
4. `rm -rf .meteor/local` to remove the local development build
5. Reinstall using `meteor npm install`
6. Start your app again